# How to save PDF preview images in Rails Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

So I am using Active Storage to attach PDFs to my models, which all works perfectly fine. As part of my project, I am asked to display PDF previews on one particular resource page that lists all available PDFs on the site for download (25+). I am using the standard config - PopplerPDFPreviewer & MuPDFPreviewer.

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.config.active_storage.previewers
=> [ActiveStorage::Previewer::PopplerPDFPreviewer, ActiveStorage::Previewer::MuPDFPreviewer, ActiveStorage::Previewer::VideoPreviewer]
```

The code:

```
- @products.each do |product|
  - if product.installation_guide.attached?
    - if product.installation_guide.previewable?
      = image_tag product.installation_guide.preview(resize: '200x200')
```

This works too, however, now and then I get a time out and too many request message since it keeps regenerating the images.

```
@net_http_res   #<Net::HTTPTooManyRequests 429 Too Many Requests readbody=true>
```

**Which is not good!**

Now [api.rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Preview.html) proposes to generate a stable URL (not view) with *.processed.service_url* that redirects to the short-lived URL that will be returned by *.service_url*.

```
blob.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]).processed.service_url
```

Ok, but again, it means that I have to keep regenerating the previews... Is there a way to generate a preview when uploading the PDF, and save that preview until it is deleted or replaced?

Answer (score 0):

This only occurs on Development environment. On production (Ubuntu 18.04) it works like a charm.